# Adding a shortcut to a programmatically added system menu option

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-7

In my application, I have a base form in which various items are added to the system menu, for example

```
 AppendMenu (SysMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, '');
 AppendMenu (SysMenu, MF_STRING, SC_Sticky, 'Sticky');
 AppendMenu (SysMenu, MF_STRING, SC_Original, 'Original');
```

How does one add keyboard shortcuts to these menu options (eg Alt-F2, Alt-F3)?

I can't use the standard method of using an accelerator (ie &Sticky for Alt-S) as the real menu captions are in Hebrew and accelerators don't seem to work properly with this language.

Comment: Check the code under TMenuItem.Shortcut or TMenuItem.SetShortcut. It probably has what you need (can't do it myself because i have not Delphi at hand)

Comment: You are looking for InsertMenuItem

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The fourth parameter to InsertMenuItem is a pointer to a MENUITEMINFO structure that contains information about the new menu item. But this structure does not contain (as far as I can see) any information about shortcuts.

Comment: You're right. I misremembered. Sorry.

Comment: Eek. Looks seriously old school. Have to add the shortcut text to the caption with a #9 separator. And then handle the shortcut invocation in a message based way. Non-trivial.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: When you write 'handle the shortcut invocation in a message based way', which message would this be? I'm currently handling WMSysCommands (my commands are defined as WM_USER + n) but it looks like I'll have to handle something else.

Comment: @No'am - There're no other messages involved, a menu item in the system menu posts a WM_SYSCOMMAND. What you're missing is an accelerator for your menu item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example that uses an [accelerator table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, AppEvnts;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FAccelTable: HACCEL;
    FAccels: array[0..1] of TAccel;
  protected
    procedure WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  SC_Sticky = 170;
  SC_Original = 180;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SysMenu: HMENU;
begin
 SysMenu := GetSystemMenu(Handle, False);
 AppendMenu (SysMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, '');
 AppendMenu (SysMenu, MF_STRING, SC_Sticky, 'Sticky'#9'Alt+F2');
 AppendMenu (SysMenu, MF_STRING, SC_Original, 'Original'#9'Alt+F3');

 FAccels[0].fVirt := FALT or FVIRTKEY;
 FAccels[0].key := VK_F2;
 FAccels[0].cmd := SC_Sticky;
 FAccels[1].fVirt := FALT or FVIRTKEY;
 FAccels[1].key := VK_F3;
 FAccels[1].cmd := SC_Original;

 FAccelTable := CreateAcceleratorTable(FAccels, 2);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DestroyAcceleratorTable(FAccelTable);
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  TranslateAccelerator(Handle, FAccelTable, Msg);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.CmdType of
    SC_Sticky: ShowMessage('sticky');
    SC_Original: ShowMessage('original');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Fantastic! Despite the fact that I've been googling all morning and checking my Delphi (and Windows) books, I've never seen an accelerator table before. This is SO at its best - everybody can learn something!

Comment: This works well. However, some applications add a custom menu item to the system menu of ALL WINDOWS - not only the own application (probably with the help of a hook). I would give a lot for being able to do that.