# Adding keyboard shortcuts to system menu

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to add a list of extra options to the form's system menu and make those options available as keyboard shortcuts.
I managed to add the options to the system menu and managed to catch the menu click for those options.

[System Menu with Shortcut List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2h44.jpg)

```
 Dim sysmenu As IntPtr = GetSystemMenu(Me.Handle, False)
 Dim shortcutMenu As IntPtr = CreateMenu()

 InsertMenu(sysmenu, 6, MenuFlags.MF_BYPOSITION Or MenuFlags.MF_POPUP, shortcutMenu, "&Shortcut List")
 InsertMenu(shortcutMenu, 0, MenuFlags.MF_STRING, 4200, String.Format("Shortcut &2 {0}Alt + B", ControlChars.Tab))
 InsertMenu(sysmenu, 7, MenuFlags.MF_BYPOSITION Or MenuFlags.MF_SEPARATOR, 0, Nothing)
```

I can't however find an example on how to add the keyboard shortcuts.
I was trying to follow an answer on another stackoverflow question ([Delphi - Adding a shortcut to a programmatically added system menu option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659300/adding-a-shortcut-to-a-programmatically-added-system-menu-option))
 and in it they're creating an accelerator table with the required shortcuts. However I couldn't find the signature for the method being called or the structure for the shortcuts.

```
        'Creating accelerator table
        Dim listaAccel As List(Of ACCEL) = New List(Of ACCEL)()
        Dim accel As New ACCEL()
        accel.fVirt = &H10 '"ALT"
        accel.key = &H42 '"B"
        accel.cmd = 4200
        listaAccel.Add(accel)

        Dim accelPointer As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(ACCEL))
        Dim arrayPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(accelPointer * 1) ' * 2)
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(listaAccel(0), arrayPointer, True)
        CreateAcceleratorTable(arrayPointer, 1)
```

I managed to find the method signature on a site but the site was empty of any other information so I'm unsure on whether it is the correct method to be called.

```
Declare Function CreateAcceleratorTable Lib "user32" Alias "CreateAcceleratorTableA" (ByRef lpaccl As IntPtr, ByVal cEntries As Integer) As Integer

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Class ACCEL
    Public fVirt As Byte
    Public key As UInt32
    Public cmd As UInt32
End Class
```

I feel that I'm close to the solution but haven't been able to find the correct information.

Extra information: 
I'm successfully capturing the click event on the new menu with the following code

```
Protected Overloads Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef message As Message)
    If message.Msg = WndValues.WM_SYSCOMMAND AndAlso message.WParam.ToInt32 = 4200 Then
        Dim i = 0    ' Shortcut 2 or Alt+B activated
    ElseIf message.Msg = WndValues.WM_SYSCOMMAND Then
        Dim j = 0
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(message)
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to set `accel.fVirt = &H10 Or 1`. 1 is the value of `FVIRTKEY`, which means that `accel.key` specifies a _virtual key code_ rather than an ASCII key. The latter is case-sensitive, which means that `B` and `b` does not count as the same key.

Comment: Also, `ACCEL` should be a `Structure`, not a `Class`. You should then declare `CreateAcceleratorTable()`'s first parameter as either `ByRef lpaccl As ACCEL` or `ByVal lpaccl As IntPtr`.

Comment: Thanks for those 2 hints. I fixed those 2 mistakes. Unfortunately it still doesn't work but those 2 changes still needed to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for replying for so late. After spending a day with this I finally managed to find a solution.

First of all there are a couple of things that needs to be corrected with the code:

1. `ACCEL` should be a `Structure`, not a `Class`.
2. `ACCEL.key` and `ACCEL.cmd` should both be declared as `UShort`, not `UInt32`.
3. It turns out that the first parameter of `CreateAcceleratorTable()` should be declared as `ByVal lpaccel As ACCEL()` (an array of `ACCEL` structures).
4. You need bitwise-or `1` (equivalent to `FVIRTKEY`) with your current `accel.fVirt` value. `FVIRTKEY` specifies that `accel.key` is a *virtual key code* rather than an ASCII code. The latter is case-sensitive, the former is not.

Now, in order for accelerators to work you need to have something that processes and translates them into a SYSCOMMAND.

Accelerators can be translated from window messages into SYSCOMMANDs using the [**`TranslateAccelerator()` function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translateacceleratora). This needs to be called every time a window message is received. However, calling it inside `WndProc` isn't enough since messages are passed only to the focused control, meaning if one of the form's controls have focus the form itself won't receive key messages.

To overcome this we can install a [**message filter**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter(v=vs.110).aspx) into the application's message pump. This will intercept every window message sent to the application before it reaches any form or control. Then we just have to pass our form's window handle to `TranslateAccelerator()` to make it send all generated SYSCOMMAND messages to it.

Finally, we should call [**`DestroyAcceleratorTable()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroyacceleratortable) before the form closes to release the accelerator table.

**Form code:**

```
'The ID of our menu item.
Const MENU_SHORTCUT2 As Integer = 4200

'A variable holding a reference to our accelerator filter.
Dim AccelMessageFilter As KeyboardAcceleratorFilter

Private Sub MainForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    'Remove our message filter and destroy the accelerator table.
    Application.RemoveMessageFilter(AccelMessageFilter)
    NativeMethods.DestroyAcceleratorTable(AccelMessageFilter.AcceleratorTable)
End Sub

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Get the system menu.
    Dim SysMenu As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetSystemMenu(Me.Handle, False)
    Dim ShortcutMenu As IntPtr = NativeMethods.CreateMenu()

    'Insert our custom menu items.
    NativeMethods.InsertMenu(SysMenu, 6, MenuFlags.MF_BYPOSITION Or MenuFlags.MF_POPUP, ShortcutMenu, "&Shortcut List")
    NativeMethods.InsertMenu(ShortcutMenu, 0, MenuFlags.MF_BYPOSITION Or MenuFlags.MF_STRING, MENU_SHORTCUT2, String.Format("Shortcut &2{0}Alt + B", ControlChars.Tab))
    NativeMethods.InsertMenu(SysMenu, 7, MenuFlags.MF_BYPOSITION Or MenuFlags.MF_SEPARATOR, 0, Nothing)

    'Create a keyboard accelerator for ALT + B.
    Dim Accel As New NativeMethods.ACCEL()
    Accel.fVirt = AcceleratorModifiers.FVIRTKEY Or AcceleratorModifiers.FALT
    Accel.key = Keys.B
    Accel.cmd = MENU_SHORTCUT2

    'Create an accelerator table.
    Dim hAccel As IntPtr = NativeMethods.CreateAcceleratorTable(New NativeMethods.ACCEL() {Accel}, 1)

    'Create our message filter.
    AccelMessageFilter = New KeyboardAcceleratorFilter(Me, hAccel, True)

    'Add the filter to the application's message pump.
    Application.AddMessageFilter(AccelMessageFilter)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WindowMessages.WM_SYSCOMMAND Then

        Select Case m.WParam.ToInt32()
            Case MENU_SHORTCUT2
                MessageBox.Show("'Shortcut 2' was pressed!")
        End Select

    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

**Message filter:**

```
Public Class KeyboardAcceleratorFilter
    Implements IMessageFilter

    Private _acceleratorTable As IntPtr
    Private _form As Form

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the pointer to the filter's accelerator table.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public ReadOnly Property AcceleratorTable As IntPtr
        Get
            Return _acceleratorTable
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets whether accelerator messages should be intercepted by the filter, stopping them from being dispatched to the form/control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property InterceptMessages As Boolean

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the form that the filter applies to.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public ReadOnly Property Form As Form
        Get
            Return _form
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) As Boolean Implements System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
        'Native MSG structure (required by TranslateAccelerator()).
        Dim Msg As New NativeMethods.MSG() With {.hwnd = Me.Form.Handle, .message = m.Msg, .wParam = m.WParam, .lParam = m.LParam}

        'Process accelerators (if any) and send the SYSCOMMAND messages to this filter's form (Msg.hwnd is set to Me.Form.Handle above).
        Dim Result As Integer = NativeMethods.TranslateAccelerator(Msg.hwnd, Me.AcceleratorTable, Msg)

        'Intercept the message if an accelerator was processed and Me.InterceptMessages = True.
        Return If(Result <> 0, Me.InterceptMessages, False)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the KeyboardAcceleratorFilter class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Form">The form that the filter applies to.</param>
    ''' <param name="AcceleratorTable">The pointer to the filter's accelerator table.</param>
    ''' <param name="InterceptMessages">Whether accelerator messages should be intercepted by the filter, stopping them from being dispatched to the form/control.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New(ByVal Form As Form, ByVal AcceleratorTable As IntPtr, ByVal InterceptMessages As Boolean)
        _form = Form
        _acceleratorTable = AcceleratorTable
        Me.InterceptMessages = InterceptMessages
    End Sub
End Class
```

**NativeMethods:**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public NotInheritable Class NativeMethods
    Private Sub New() 'Private constructor as we're not supposed to create instances of this class.
    End Sub

#Region "WinAPI Functions"
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function GetSystemMenu(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bRevert As Boolean) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function CreateMenu() As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Public Shared Function InsertMenu(ByVal hMenu As IntPtr, ByVal uPosition As UInteger, ByVal uFlags As MenuFlags, ByVal uIDNewItem As IntPtr, ByVal lpNewMenu As String) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function CreateAcceleratorTable(ByVal lpaccel As ACCEL(), ByVal cAccel As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function TranslateAccelerator(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hAccel As IntPtr, ByRef lpMsg As MSG) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function DestroyAcceleratorTable(ByVal hAccel As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function
#End Region

#Region "Structures"
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure ACCEL
        Public fVirt As AcceleratorModifiers
        Public key As UShort
        Public cmd As UShort
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure MSG
        Public hwnd As IntPtr
        Public message As UInteger
        Public wParam As IntPtr
        Public lParam As IntPtr
        Public time As UInteger
        Public pt As POINT
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure POINT
        Public x As Integer
        Public y As Integer
    End Structure
#End Region

End Class

#Region "Enumerations"
<Flags()> _
Public Enum AcceleratorModifiers As Byte
    FVIRTKEY = 1
    FSHIFT = &H4
    FCONTROL = &H8
    FALT = &H10
End Enum

Public Enum MenuFlags As Integer
    MF_BYCOMMAND = &H0
    MF_BYPOSITION = &H400
    MF_BITMAP = &H4
    MF_CHECKED = &H8
    MF_DISABLED = &H2
    MF_ENABLED = &H0
    MF_GRAYED = &H1
    MF_MENUBARBREAK = &H20
    MF_MENUBREAK = &H40
    MF_OWNERDRAW = &H100
    MF_POPUP = &H10
    MF_SEPARATOR = &H800
    MF_STRING = &H0
    MF_UNCHECKED = &H0
End Enum

Public Enum WindowMessages As Integer
    WM_COMMAND = &H111
    WM_SYSCOMMAND = &H112
End Enum
#End Region
```

Comment: You truly went above and beyond. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @ricardo : Glad I could be of help! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Could you explain to me what the InterceptMessages Boolean does on the KeyboardAcceleratorFilter?
I am trying to add the same functionalities with a different shortcut to an MDI Child of the main form but it's only capturing the events of the main form. I tried turning that flag to false but I didn't notice any changes.

Comment: @ricardo : If the Boolean is `True` it just stops the key message itself (in this case `ALT + B`) from reaching any form or control. -- MDI is outdated by the way. Use `Me.Controls.Add` instead to add a form within a form.